# Formulas for special elements of the nil-Hecke ring

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, schubert-calculus

Kostant and Kumar introduced the nil-Hecke ring for a crystallographic Coxeter group, which we will take to be $S_\infty$, which is the ring generated as a left module over the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ (where the number of indeterminates is infinite, and the coefficient ring is not in the center) by products of divided difference operators,
$$\partial^{s_i}=\frac{1}{x_i-x_{i+1}}(1-s_i)$$
These products satisfy braid relations and aggregate to form divided difference operators $\partial^w$ for $w\in S_\infty$ that form a basis for the ring. My dissertation studied a coproduct on this ring and identified the coefficients of the operators $\partial_u^w$ where
$$\partial^wp=\sum_{u\in S_\infty}\partial^u(p)\partial_u^w$$
for all polynomials $p$. These turn out to be the structure constants of the $T$-equivariant cohomology ring of the complete flag variety, and hence a certain positivity result applies but no positive formula is yet known for them (finding one would be a huge deal, currently considered way out of reach). Some special cases of these have known positive formulas, for example the group elements $w=\partial_w^w$.

There are elements of the nil-Hecke ring known as isobaric divided difference operators, which are products of operators of the form
$$\pi^{s_i}=\partial^{s_i}x_i$$
These also satisfy braid relations and aggregate to form isobaric divided difference operators $\pi^w$ for $w\in S_\infty$ that can be expressed in terms of divided difference operators.

I recently proved, via a combinatorial formula, that if we write
$$\pi^w=\sum_u p_u^w(x)\partial^u$$
(where $x$ is short for the infinite sequence of indetermines) then $p_u^w(x)$ has nonnegative integer coefficients for all $u$ and $w$. I have a similar positive formula for the operators $\theta^w$ that are products of $\theta^{s_i}=x_{i+1}\partial^{s_i}$, which are closely related. In fact,
$$\pi^w=\sum_{u\leq w}\theta^u$$
Hence one could say the formula for $\pi^w$ is redundant, but it's nicer and faster than summing up the smaller thetas. I haven't written this up in a suitably publishable form yet, so you won't find it on the internet.

My question is: is there any related work expressing specific operators in terms of divided difference operators with polynomial coefficients? I was unable to find anything myself, besides things like a formula for $\partial^{w_0}$ in terms of elements of $S_n$, or the stuff in Macdonald's Notes on Schubert Polynomials.